# What is DocValues in Solr.

Tags: sorting, solr, inverted-index

I am new to Solr. I read that Solr is using inverted index which is efficient for quick search results. But if query includes sorting,faceting, people recommend to use docvalues. So my question is what is docvalues and why we need to use in above cases and also how inverting index is not efficient in above cases. **Please give a detailed explanation in with example if possible.**

Answer (score 3):

To complete Hector's answer, I would say that the inverted index is efficient to match documents given a main search query.

Now when it comes to filter / sort / do faceting, Solr acts on a resultset, it is already dealing with a list of matched documents, and any sub query will intersect or union with the main resultset.

At this point, we can think logically of a documents-to-something situation : for example, if you were to sort an arbitrary list of docIDs by *fieldX*, you would actually reorder fieldX values and get the corresponding - *sorted* - docIDs.

So, if the fieldCache is built with docValues enabled for the concerned fields, having document-to-value mapping ready to be used will drastically improve the use of the fieldCache.

We may also (maybe somewhat imprecisely) refer to warm cache vs cold cache.

Comment: That makes perfect sense but why does the documentation mention sorting & faceting without mentioning filtering explicitly? Could filtering be more performant if the field is specified as "indexed" rather than "docValues"?

Comment: @AhmadAbdelghany I think the doc is not explicit because _having document-to-value mapping ready to be used drastically improve the use of the fieldCache_ does not mean filter queries require that mapping, actually they don't in most cases : filtering is just making unions or intersections of doc IDs matched from basic `field:value` q & fq. But, more complex fq (particularly when using function query) work with actual field values which need to be loaded at some point, in which case having docValues enabled for the involved fields is worth it. A field can be both indexed and use docValues.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that DocValues are an optimization to help with memory utilization and performance for some of the other features of Solr that people associate with searching.

From the [Solr guide](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/docvalues.html):

> DocValues are a way of recording field values internally that is more
>   efficient for some purposes, such as sorting and faceting, than
>   traditional indexing.
>
> Why DocValues?
>
> The standard way that Solr builds the index is with an inverted index.
>   This style builds a list of terms found in all the documents in the
>   index and next to each term is a list of documents that the term
>   appears in (as well as how many times the term appears in that
>   document). This makes search very fast - since users search by terms,
>   having a ready list of term-to-document values makes the query process
>   faster.
>
> For other features that we now commonly associate with search, such as
>   sorting, faceting, and highlighting, this approach is not very
>   efficient. The faceting engine, for example, must look up each term
>   that appears in each document that will make up the result set and
>   pull the document IDs in order to build the facet list. In Solr, this
>   is maintained in memory, and can be slow to load (depending on the
>   number of documents, terms, etc.).
>
> In Lucene 4.0, a new approach was introduced. DocValue fields are now
>   column-oriented fields with a document-to-value mapping built at index
>   time. This approach promises to relieve some of the memory
>   requirements of the fieldCache and make lookups for faceting, sorting,
>   and grouping much faster.

Comment: Inverted index defines list of documents for each term(token). So for faceting it is very easy to use inverted index to give counts right?. So how docvalues give better optimization here